# newly appended data to be shown and scrolled down instead of up?

Tags: php, jquery, html

i am appending chat data to the div but problem is that new messages are show at the top of chat window instead of showing at the bottom>plz help to show  newly  messages at the bottom.

And also how can i style(different  bg colour etc ) to newly appended data?

```
        $.post('load.php', { tocom:id}, function(data) {
        $('#chat_window').html(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add to the end, [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add at the beginning.

Comment: .append loads all the chat data instead of only new messags